# Hotel rooms prices: how to manage discounts that changes according to some conditions

Tags: mysql, database-design, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm writing an app to manage rooms in a Hotel and I've to design the DB to manage discounted price.
I've already made the Room and Price tables and now I've to create some tables where I can store discounts that the admins could apply according to some conditions. The admins could create new discounts too.
For example:

- An user could get 10% discount if the reservation starts in September.
- An user could get 10% discount if he is going to book the room during 2 weeks

So, here are my simplified tables (I omitted fields and relations that are not related to the question):

**Rooms:**

```
id | name
---|----------------
 1 | Trafalgar Square
 2 | Piccadilly
```

**Prices:**

```
id | room_id  | base | promotion 
---|----------|------|-----------
 1 |    1     | 10   | 8
 2 |    2     | 25   | 20
```

How can I store conditions as the ones stated above?
I'm using Rails and the first solution I thought about was to create a table where I can store the discount is going to be applied and the condition to apply it.
I thought the field condition as a SQL snippet; something like `Reservation.start_date > [date]`, thus I could apply more discounts concatenating them in Rails. 
But this is a very ugly solution and is coupled with the DBRMS, so I'd like to avoid this choice.

Do you know how can I implement something to solve this problem?
I hope to have explained the problem clearly.

Comment: It strikes me that a relational database isn't the way to do this - a relational database is for storing data, not logic.

Comment: OP, @amaidment - I think you _have_ to use a db somewhere, since discounts are attached to rooms. I'd have a column of shortcodes, where a shortcode 'september-10-promo' runs a piece of business logic on the final price (`discounts.september10promo`?), taking into account whatever it needs to (start date, booking length, etc). I agree that you shouldn't be storing SQL snippets unless there is no alternative - that could get messy very quickly `:)`

Comment: @amaidment, I know this is logic and DB is for storing data, but in this case I'm dealing with a 'dynamic logic' because the admins could create rules to apply discounts. How could I write the business logic if I don't know its rules in advance?

Comment: @halfer, I like your solution but I can't see a way to create new rules dynamically ; or are you talking about storing the business logic code into the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an expanded version of my comment. I agree that putting in SQL/executable code in the db is generally a bad idea, and I think you can avoid that in this case.

I would do it this way:

```
promotion
------------------------------------------------------------
id (pk) | shortname (uniq) | params?   |  serialised_params?
1       | september_promo  | ...       |
2       | long_stay        | ...       |
------------------------------------------------------------

room_promotion
----------------------------------------------------
room_id (fk) | promotion_id (fk) | serialised_params
1            | 1                 | { discount=10; start_date=x; end_date=y }
2            | 2                 | { length=14 }
----------------------------------------------------
```

This approach gives you maximum flexibility with the kinds of promotion you might want to run. Since each promotion has a number of parameters depending on the business logic, I've suggested that in the per-room case you have a column of serialised parameters, so you don't have a large number of unused columns in this table. *Do bear in mind that this does break a few relational rules, but used sparingly and with an awareness of its limitations, it is a useful approach*.

You could equally have parameters or serialised parameters against each promotion row too (say if you knew that all uses of the 'long_stay' promo would be for 14 days).

Note I've arranged the 'room_promotion' table so that more than one promotion could be applied to a room. You could make `(room_id, promotion_id)` a primary key if you're sure that one will *always* only be applicable at one time.

OK, so now you have a mechanism by which 'promotion rules' can be applied. But, the business logic still belongs in your code. So, look up the shortname, camel-case it, and then use a dynamic look-up mechanism in Ruby to apply the discount. I don't use Ruby, but in PHP sketch-form it might look like this:

```
    Get object $Bill (prior to discount being applied)
    $Discount = DiscountFactory::getInstance(
        'september_promo',
        unserialize($serialised)
    );
    $Bill->applyDiscount($Discount);
    Display modified bill
```

Internally, I reckon `september_promo` gets converted to `SeptemberPromo`, which is a class thus (sorry, PHP again):

```
class SeptemberPromo extends Promotion
{
    // Add in concrete implementation of abstract method here
    public function executeDiscount($Bill) { ... }
}
```

In turn, Promotion can have an abstract method that is used by `applyDiscount()` to determine what discount to apply, given the per-room values, the per-promo values, and the details of the bill.

So long as you keep your discount business logic fairly generic, your hotel managers will be able to customise it using the serialised parameters, rather than needing new Ruby code for every fresh promotion (unless they want a promotion *type* that is new). With that in mind, *SeptemberPromo* is perhaps too specific - maybe *MonthSpecial*?

Obviously you'll need to build a UI to let a hotel manager store new `promotion` and `room_promotion` rows, but that should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly suggest you investigate using some type of Rules Engine for processing this.

The issue is that Hotels, like many industries, use an extremely fluid way of pricing.  Some of it seems whimsical, others bear little resemblance to thought, and all are difficult to create a structured approach for.

For example, Room is discounted by 10% if a single night is booked and the client makes the booking after 11:00pm... unless it's a Friday or Saturday night or if the hotel is at 80%+ capacity.

This rule might be interrupted if it's January where the standard discount is 15%.

That rule might be interrupted if a convention is scheduled to be in town.  At which point the room rate is raised by 30%.

---

An alternate approach would be to simply forgo having the system automatically compute room rates and instead rely on hotel staff to set them at the point of booking.  In this case you'd just show some guidelines on the current "specials".

Granted, that's not as sexy as doing it automatically, but if the hotel in question isn't going to buy a COTS that already does this then it stands to reason they probably aren't going to pay the costs necessary to properly develop it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris for your response..Finally I spoke with the client and we decided to write only hardcoded rules for now. Meanwhile I found Drool to be a good solution (and I've work with Java during 8 years) for the future if the client will want to make dynamics rules.

Answer (score 2):

Brilliant question.

I've never worked on a hotel booking system, but have worked on ecommerce projects which had discount strategies, and the bad news is that this can become extremely complex very quickly.

For instance, you may have multiple discounts that apply to a given booking, and you need to work out if they are cumulative, or mutually exclusive (if there's a "10% of every booking" discount, and the booking qualifies for a "newly-wed 25% offer", do you give 10%, 25% or 35%?). If you have to deal with tax, it gets even weirder - if the total booking has multiple products, with different tax rates, how do you calculate tax after applying a discount?

If you're on the hook for building a system that allows users to specify new (types of) discount, with all the rules that go with that, your project will become rather large, very complex, and obsessed with the discount engine.

If that's the world you're in, take @Chris Lively's answer. Invest in a rules engine, and prepare to spend the next significant period of time explaining how discounts work, what "and", "or", "xor" etc. mean.

Ideally, though, you might spend a bit more time refining the actual, current requirements. If you only have to solve for 5 real examples, the options are a lot more limited than building a general purpose discounting engine. Look at the strategy pattern and the composite pattern. If it's not "general purpose", there's no shame in making a "summer 2012" discount strategy with the validity dates hardcoded rather than stored in the database.

Comment: For me is the first time too and you summarize very well saying this:
your project will become rather large, very complex, and obsessed with the discount engine.

Comment: Good advice, especially about refining the requirements.  It helps both the developer and the client to have the right expectations going into what has the potential to be a morass.

Comment: I could not agree with you more: good advice!!and when I met the client I told him about all this in Neville advice.

Answer (score 2):

It is often the case that the reservations staff is given the authority to apply different discounts. In other words, the rules for the discounts are only spot checked, retrospectively.

Having the system automatically check eligibility for a given discount will quickly become:

- too complex to understand (for the admins trying to add new discounts and their rules)
- too complex to implement the system (need to anticipate an ever growing list of situations)
- too brittle (there will always be "exceptions" which are perfectly reasonable and appropriate.)
- impossible for some discounts. Eg how can someone "prove" that they are attending a wedding and thus are eligible for the wedding group's discount.

Often the discounts are a matter of marketing. In such cases, you want to know which discount the customer asked for (the "Jones wedding discount") rather than strictly controlling the eligibility of the discount via a rule.

A more useful aspect of the discount system would be for the checkin system to see if the discount requires the customer to show proof of discount eligibility and to prompt the check-in clerk if so. Eg ask for an employee id if a company's contract discount rate is used on the reservation.

A hotel reservations and room management system is very complicated. You should understand why the hotel is not using COTS (commercial off the shelf) software for it.